# I'm trying to connect my flutter project to sqlite studio editro but I'm using sgflite database

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

at first this my database file then I created seperate file in vsc and then I created floder  then  added the exported function to it.

```
 `import 'package:baby_tracker/models/user.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
 import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
 import 'package:path/path.dart';
 import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
 import 'dart:io';

 class SqlDb {
  static Database? _db;

    Future<Database?> get db async {
if (_db == null) {
  _db = await intialdb();
  return _db;
} else {
  return _db;
}
    }

     intialdb() async {
String databasepath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasepath, 'babytracker.db');
Database trackerdb = await openDatabase(path,
    onCreate: _oncreate, version: 6, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
return trackerdb;
   }

    _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
print("Updated");
   }

    _oncreate(Database db, int version) async {
await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE "complete_information"(
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "baby_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "first_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "gender" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "date_of_birth" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "weight" REAL NOT NULL,
  "height" REAL NOT NULL


)
   ''');
await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE "user_authorization"(
  "userid" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "useremail" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "userpassword" TEXT NOT NULL
)
    ''');

print("Table is done");
     }

       Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> readData(
  String table, Map<String, dynamic> conditions) async {
Database? trackerdb = await db;

List<String> whereConditions = [];
List<dynamic> whereValues = [];

conditions.forEach((key, value) {
  whereConditions.add('$key = ?');
  whereValues.add(value);
});

String whereClause = whereConditions.join(" AND ");

List<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await trackerdb!.query(
  table,
  where: whereClause,
  whereArgs: whereValues,
);

return response;
    }

     Future<int> insertData(String table, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
Database? trackerdb = await db;
int response = await trackerdb!.insert(table, data);
return response;
      }

      updateData(String sql) async {
Database? trackerdb = await db;
int response = await trackerdb!.rawUpdate(sql);
return response;
      }

         deleteData(String sql) async {
    Database? trackerdb = await db;
       int response = await trackerdb!.rawDelete(sql);
        return response;
        }
        then added the exported function to it 
       Future<void> exportDatabase(String exportPath) async {
      try {
  // Get the database instance.
  Database db = await _db!;

  // Get the database file path.
  String dbFilePath = await db.path;

  // Construct the sqlite3 command.
  String sqlite3Command = 'sqlite3 $dbFilePath .dump > $exportPath';

  // Execute the sqlite3 command using Process.
  ProcessResult result =
      await Process.run('sqlite3', ['-batch', sqlite3Command]);

  // Check if the export was successful.
     if (result.exitCode == 0) {
    print('Database exported successfully!');
    } else {
    print('Error exporting database: ${result.stderr}');
    }

  await db.close();
   } catch (e) {
  print('Error exporting database: $e');
   }
       }
    }
```

I created seperate file in vsc name as exported_database.dart and then I created floder in my computer name as SQLiteDatabases then I created a file inside it to exprot the database to it to import it to  sqlite studio just like this ,so when I run the app there's no thing happend ,I checked the so what I have to ?
`
import 'package:baby_tracker/sqldb.dart';

```
    Future<void> main() async {
    // Get the path where you want to export the database file.
    String exportPath =
   'C:/Users/NAFOURI/Desktop/SQLiteDatabases/exported_database.db';
    
    await SqlDb().exportDatabase(exportPath);

  print('Database exported successfully!');
     }
```